# Как сгладить ряд данных?

Tags: python, numpy

Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно сгладить статистический ряд?

Есть задача - скорректировать коэффициенты сезонности. Для этого я для определенных периодов и групп товаров я умножал коэффициенты на необходимое значение, но такая корректировка резкая и хотелось бы что бы показатели изменялись равномерно.

```
json_data = '{"date":{"0":1672531200000,"1":1672617600000,"2":1672704000000,"3":1672790400000,"4":1672876800000,"5":1672963200000,"6":1673049600000,"7":1673136000000,"8":1673222400000,"9":1673308800000,"10":1673395200000,"11":1673481600000,"12":1673568000000,"13":1673654400000,"14":1673740800000,"15":1673827200000,"16":1673913600000,"17":1674000000000,"18":1674086400000,"19":1674172800000,"20":1674259200000,"21":1674345600000,"22":1674432000000,"23":1674518400000,"24":1674604800000,"25":1674691200000,"26":1674777600000,"27":1674864000000,"28":1674950400000,"29":1675036800000,"30":1675123200000,"31":1675209600000,"32":1675296000000,"33":1675382400000,"34":1675468800000,"35":1675555200000,"36":1675641600000,"37":1675728000000,"38":1675814400000,"39":1675900800000,"40":1675987200000,"41":1676073600000,"42":1676160000000,"43":1676246400000,"44":1676332800000,"45":1676419200000,"46":1676505600000,"47":1676592000000,"48":1676678400000,"49":1676764800000,"50":1676851200000,"51":1676937600000,"52":1677024000000,"53":1677110400000,"54":1677196800000,"55":1677283200000,"56":1677369600000,"57":1677456000000,"58":1677542400000,"59":1677628800000,"60":1677715200000,"61":1677801600000,"62":1677888000000,"63":1677974400000,"64":1678060800000,"65":1678147200000,"66":1678233600000,"67":1678320000000,"68":1678406400000,"69":1678492800000,"70":1678579200000,"71":1678665600000,"72":1678752000000,"73":1678838400000,"74":1678924800000,"75":1679011200000,"76":1679097600000,"77":1679184000000,"78":1679270400000,"79":1679356800000,"80":1679443200000,"81":1679529600000,"82":1679616000000,"83":1679702400000,"84":1679788800000,"85":1679875200000,"86":1679961600000,"87":1680048000000,"88":1680134400000,"89":1680220800000,"90":1680307200000,"91":1680393600000,"92":1680480000000,"93":1680566400000,"94":1680652800000,"95":1680739200000,"96":1680825600000,"97":1680912000000,"98":1680998400000,"99":1681084800000,"100":1681171200000,"101":1681257600000,"102":1681344000000,"103":1681430400000,"104":1681516800000,"105":1681603200000,"106":1681689600000,"107":1681776000000,"108":1681862400000,"109":1681948800000,"110":1682035200000,"111":1682121600000,"112":1682208000000,"113":1682294400000,"114":1682380800000,"115":1682467200000,"116":1682553600000,"117":1682640000000,"118":1682726400000,"119":1682812800000,"120":1682899200000,"121":1682985600000,"122":1683072000000,"123":1683158400000,"124":1683244800000,"125":1683331200000,"126":1683417600000,"127":1683504000000,"128":1683590400000,"129":1683676800000,"130":1683763200000,"131":1683849600000,"132":1683936000000,"133":1684022400000,"134":1684108800000,"135":1684195200000,"136":1684281600000,"137":1684368000000,"138":1684454400000,"139":1684540800000,"140":1684627200000,"141":1684713600000,"142":1684800000000,"143":1684886400000,"144":1684972800000,"145":1685059200000,"146":1685145600000,"147":1685232000000,"148":1685318400000,"149":1685404800000,"150":1685491200000,"151":1685577600000,"152":1685664000000,"153":1685750400000,"154":1685836800000,"155":1685923200000,"156":1686009600000,"157":1686096000000,"158":1686182400000,"159":1686268800000,"160":1686355200000,"161":1686441600000,"162":1686528000000,"163":1686614400000,"164":1686700800000,"165":1686787200000,"166":1686873600000,"167":1686960000000,"168":1687046400000,"169":1687132800000,"170":1687219200000,"171":1687305600000,"172":1687392000000,"173":1687478400000,"174":1687564800000,"175":1687651200000,"176":1687737600000,"177":1687824000000,"178":1687910400000,"179":1687996800000,"180":1688083200000,"181":1688169600000,"182":1688256000000,"183":1688342400000,"184":1688428800000,"185":1688515200000,"186":1688601600000,"187":1688688000000,"188":1688774400000,"189":1688860800000,"190":1688947200000,"191":1689033600000,"192":1689120000000,"193":1689206400000,"194":1689292800000,"195":1689379200000,"196":1689465600000,"197":1689552000000,"198":1689638400000,"199":1689724800000,"200":1689811200000,"201":1689897600000,"202":1689984000000,"203":1690070400000,"204":1690156800000,"205":1690243200000,"206":1690329600000,"207":1690416000000,"208":1690502400000,"209":1690588800000,"210":1690675200000,"211":1690761600000,"212":1690848000000,"213":1690934400000,"214":1691020800000,"215":1691107200000,"216":1691193600000,"217":1691280000000,"218":1691366400000,"219":1691452800000,"220":1691539200000,"221":1691625600000,"222":1691712000000,"223":1691798400000,"224":1691884800000,"225":1691971200000,"226":1692057600000,"227":1692144000000,"228":1692230400000,"229":1692316800000,"230":1692403200000,"231":1692489600000,"232":1692576000000,"233":1692662400000,"234":1692748800000,"235":1692835200000,"236":1692921600000,"237":1693008000000,"238":1693094400000,"239":1693180800000,"240":1693267200000,"241":1693353600000,"242":1693440000000,"243":1693526400000,"244":1693612800000,"245":1693699200000,"246":1693785600000,"247":1693872000000,"248":1693958400000,"249":1694044800000,"250":1694131200000,"251":1694217600000,"252":1694304000000,"253":1694390400000,"254":1694476800000,"255":1694563200000,"256":1694649600000,"257":1694736000000,"258":1694822400000,"259":1694908800000,"260":1694995200000,"261":1695081600000,"262":1695168000000,"263":1695254400000,"264":1695340800000,"265":1695427200000,"266":1695513600000,"267":1695600000000,"268":1695686400000,"269":1695772800000,"270":1695859200000,"271":1695945600000,"272":1696032000000,"273":1696118400000,"274":1696204800000,"275":1696291200000,"276":1696377600000,"277":1696464000000,"278":1696550400000,"279":1696636800000,"280":1696723200000,"281":1696809600000,"282":1696896000000,"283":1696982400000,"284":1697068800000,"285":1697155200000,"286":1697241600000,"287":1697328000000,"288":1697414400000,"289":1697500800000,"290":1697587200000,"291":1697673600000,"292":1697760000000,"293":1697846400000,"294":1697932800000,"295":1698019200000,"296":1698105600000,"297":1698192000000,"298":1698278400000,"299":1698364800000,"300":1698451200000,"301":1698537600000,"302":1698624000000,"303":1698710400000,"304":1698796800000,"305":1698883200000,"306":1698969600000,"307":1699056000000,"308":1699142400000,"309":1699228800000,"310":1699315200000,"311":1699401600000,"312":1699488000000,"313":1699574400000,"314":1699660800000,"315":1699747200000,"316":1699833600000,"317":1699920000000,"318":1700006400000,"319":1700092800000,"320":1700179200000,"321":1700265600000,"322":1700352000000,"323":1700438400000,"324":1700524800000,"325":1700611200000,"326":1700697600000,"327":1700784000000,"328":1700870400000,"329":1700956800000,"330":1701043200000,"331":1701129600000,"332":1701216000000,"333":1701302400000,"334":1701388800000,"335":1701475200000,"336":1701561600000,"337":1701648000000,"338":1701734400000,"339":1701820800000,"340":1701907200000,"341":1701993600000,"342":1702080000000,"343":1702166400000,"344":1702252800000,"345":1702339200000,"346":1702425600000,"347":1702512000000,"348":1702598400000,"349":1702684800000,"350":1702771200000,"351":1702857600000,"352":1702944000000,"353":1703030400000,"354":1703116800000,"355":1703203200000,"356":1703289600000,"357":1703376000000,"358":1703462400000,"359":1703548800000,"360":1703635200000,"361":1703721600000,"362":1703808000000,"363":1703894400000,"364":1703980800000},"coef":{"0":9.6300001144,"1":8.8699998856,"2":8.0600004196,"3":7.2100000381,"4":6.3200001717,"5":5.4200000763,"6":4.5199999809,"7":3.6300001144,"8":2.7799999714,"9":1.9700000286,"10":1.2300000191,"11":0.5699999928,"12":0.0,"13":-0.4600000083,"14":-0.8000000119,"15":-1.0,"16":-1.0599999428,"17":-0.9700000286,"18":-0.7300000191,"19":-0.3300000131,"20":0.2300000042,"21":0.9399999976,"22":1.8099999428,"23":2.8199999332,"24":3.9700000286,"25":5.2399997711,"26":6.6199998856,"27":8.1000003815,"28":9.6499996185,"29":11.2600002289,"30":12.9099998474,"31":14.5699996948,"32":16.2099990845,"33":17.8299999237,"34":19.3899993896,"35":20.8600006104,"36":22.2399997711,"37":23.4899997711,"38":24.5900001526,"39":25.5300006866,"40":26.2800006866,"41":26.8299999237,"42":27.1800003052,"43":27.2999992371,"44":27.2000007629,"45":26.8600006104,"46":26.2999992371,"47":25.5,"48":24.4699993134,"49":23.2299995422,"50":21.7800006866,"51":20.1399993896,"52":18.3299999237,"53":16.3600006104,"54":14.2600002289,"55":12.0600004196,"56":9.7600002289,"57":7.4200000763,"58":5.0399999619,"59":2.6600000858,"60":0.3100000024,"61":-1.9900000095,"62":-4.2100000381,"63":-6.3299999237,"64":-8.3199996948,"65":-10.1700000763,"66":-11.8400001526,"67":-13.3400001526,"68":-14.6400003433,"69":-15.7299995422,"70":-16.6100006104,"71":-17.2800006866,"72":-17.7299995422,"73":-17.9599990845,"74":-17.9899997711,"75":-17.8199996948,"76":-17.4699993134,"77":-16.9400005341,"78":-16.25,"79":-15.4300003052,"80":-14.4899997711,"81":-13.4499998093,"82":-12.3400001526,"83":-11.1700000763,"84":-9.970000267,"85":-8.75,"86":-7.5399999619,"87":-6.3600001335,"88":-5.2300000191,"89":-4.1500000954,"90":-3.1400001049,"91":-2.2200000286,"92":-1.3799999952,"93":-0.6399999857,"94":-0.0099999998,"95":0.5299999714,"96":0.9599999785,"97":1.2999999523,"98":1.5499999523,"99":1.7200000286,"100":1.8099999428,"101":1.8300000429,"102":1.7999999523,"103":1.7300000191,"104":1.6200000048,"105":1.5,"106":1.3600000143,"107":1.2300000191,"108":1.1000000238,"109":0.9900000095,"110":0.8999999762,"111":0.8399999738,"112":0.8000000119,"113":0.8000000119,"114":0.8299999833,"115":0.8899999857,"116":0.9800000191,"117":1.0800000429,"118":1.2000000477,"119":1.3200000525,"120":1.4400000572,"121":1.5499999523,"122":1.6399999857,"123":1.7000000477,"124":1.7200000286,"125":1.7000000477,"126":1.6200000048,"127":1.5,"128":1.3099999428,"129":1.0599999428,"130":0.7400000095,"131":0.3700000048,"132":-0.0700000003,"133":-0.5600000024,"134":-1.0900000334,"135":-1.6699999571,"136":-2.2699999809,"137":-2.8900001049,"138":-3.5199999809,"139":-4.1399998665,"140":-4.75,"141":-5.3200001717,"142":-5.8499999046,"143":-6.3200001717,"144":-6.7199997902,"145":-7.0500001907,"146":-7.2899999619,"147":-7.4299998283,"148":-7.4800000191,"149":-7.4200000763,"150":-7.2600002289,"151":-7.0,"152":-6.6500000954,"153":-6.1999998093,"154":-5.6599998474,"155":-5.0599999428,"156":-4.3800001144,"157":-3.6600000858,"158":-2.8900001049,"159":-2.0999999046,"160":-1.2999999523,"161":-0.5099999905,"162":0.2700000107,"163":1.0099999905,"164":1.7000000477,"165":2.3399999142,"166":2.9200000763,"167":3.4100000858,"168":3.8299999237,"169":4.1500000954,"170":4.3899998665,"171":4.5399999619,"172":4.6100001335,"173":4.5900001526,"174":4.5,"175":4.3299999237,"176":4.1100001335,"177":3.8399999142,"178":3.5399999619,"179":3.2100000381,"180":2.8699998856,"181":2.5299999714,"182":2.2000000477,"183":1.8999999762,"184":1.6299999952,"185":1.4099999666,"186":1.2400000095,"187":1.1200000048,"188":1.0700000525,"189":1.0800000429,"190":1.1499999762,"191":1.2799999714,"192":1.4700000286,"193":1.7100000381,"194":2.0,"195":2.3099999428,"196":2.6500000954,"197":2.9900000095,"198":3.3399999142,"199":3.6700000763,"200":3.9700000286,"201":4.2300000191,"202":4.4400000572,"203":4.5900001526,"204":4.6700000763,"205":4.6599998474,"206":4.5700001717,"207":4.3899998665,"208":4.1100001335,"209":3.7400000095,"210":3.2699999809,"211":2.7200000286,"212":2.0799999237,"213":1.3600000143,"214":0.5799999833,"215":-0.25,"216":-1.1299999952,"217":-2.0499999523,"218":-2.9800000191,"219":-3.9200000763,"220":-4.8499999046,"221":-5.75,"222":-6.6300001144,"223":-7.4600000381,"224":-8.2299995422,"225":-8.9399995804,"226":-9.5799999237,"227":-10.1499996185,"228":-10.6300001144,"229":-11.0399999619,"230":-11.3699998856,"231":-11.6099996567,"232":-11.7899999619,"233":-11.8999996185,"234":-11.9399995804,"235":-11.9399995804,"236":-11.8900003433,"237":-11.8100004196,"238":-11.7100000381,"239":-11.6000003815,"240":-11.4799995422,"241":-11.3800001144,"242":-11.2899999619,"243":-11.2299995422,"244":-11.1999998093,"245":-11.2100000381,"246":-11.2700004578,"247":-11.3599996567,"248":-11.5100002289,"249":-11.6899995804,"250":-11.9200000763,"251":-12.1899995804,"252":-12.4899997711,"253":-12.8100004196,"254":-13.1499996185,"255":-13.5,"256":-13.8500003815,"257":-14.1800003052,"258":-14.5,"259":-14.779999733,"260":-15.0200004578,"261":-15.2100000381,"262":-15.3400001526,"263":-15.4099998474,"264":-15.3999996185,"265":-15.3199996948,"266":-15.1599998474,"267":-14.9200000763,"268":-14.6099996567,"269":-14.2100000381,"270":-13.7399997711,"271":-13.2100000381,"272":-12.6000003815,"273":-11.9499998093,"274":-11.2399997711,"275":-10.5,"276":-9.7299995422,"277":-8.9399995804,"278":-8.1400003433,"279":-7.3400001526,"280":-6.5399999619,"281":-5.7699999809,"282":-5.0300002098,"283":-4.3200001717,"284":-3.6500000954,"285":-3.0199999809,"286":-2.4500000477,"287":-1.9299999475,"288":-1.3500000238,"289":-0.9499999881,"290":-0.6000000238,"291":-0.3000000119,"292":-0.0500000007,"293":0.1599999964,"294":0.3300000131,"295":0.4699999988,"296":0.5799999833,"297":0.6600000262,"298":0.7300000191,"299":0.7799999714,"300":0.8299999833,"301":0.8700000048,"302":0.9200000167,"303":0.9700000286,"304":1.0299999714,"305":1.0900000334,"306":1.1599999666,"307":1.25,"308":1.3400000334,"309":1.4400000572,"310":1.5499999523,"311":1.6599999666,"312":1.7799999714,"313":1.8899999857,"314":2.0099999905,"315":2.1099998951,"316":2.2200000286,"317":2.3099999428,"318":2.3900001049,"319":2.4600000381,"320":2.5199999809,"321":2.5699999332,"322":2.5999999046,"323":2.6300001144,"324":2.6500000954,"325":2.6700000763,"326":2.6900000572,"327":2.7100000381,"328":2.7400000095,"329":2.7899999619,"330":2.8499999046,"331":2.9400000572,"332":3.0499999523,"333":3.1900000572,"334":3.3699998856,"335":3.5899999142,"336":3.8499999046,"337":4.1500000954,"338":4.5,"339":4.8899998665,"340":5.3200001717,"341":5.7800002098,"342":6.2899999619,"343":6.8200001717,"344":7.3699998856,"345":7.9400000572,"346":8.5100002289,"347":9.0900001526,"348":9.6499996185,"349":10.1999998093,"350":10.7100000381,"351":11.1800003052,"352":11.6000003815,"353":11.970000267,"354":12.2600002289,"355":12.4799995422,"356":12.6099996567,"357":12.6599998474,"358":12.6099996567,"359":12.4600000381,"360":12.220000267,"361":11.8800001144,"362":11.4499998093,"363":10.9200000763,"364":10.3100004196}}'
```

Вот так выглядит к. сезонности до корректировок:

[image]

А вот так если я выполню следующий код:

```
def step_3(i): 
    df_main_comp_test.loc[(df_main_comp_test['date'] >= '17.07.2023') & 
                          (df_main_comp_test['group'] == 'Группа А'), i] *= 0.65
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы сгладить показатели в даты изменения. Я попытался сделать это примерно так, но не вышло.

```
def step_3(i, coef): 
        df_main_comp_test.loc[(df_main_comp_test['date'] >= '17.07.2023') & 
                              (df_main_comp_test['group'] == 'Группа А'), i] *= 0.65
    le = df.__len__()
    arrs = np.arange(start=0, stop=le, step=1)
    otkl = arrs.sum() / coef
    arrs = arrs / otkl
    df *= arrs
```

Как возможно нормализовать данный отрезок?
P.S: [Ссылка на пример данных](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pH3VLfuncmelE-DmixWltBG45x2S6XJz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос данные. Подогнать можно если буду данные.

Comment: Умножьте не на постоянный коэффициент, а на плавную оконную функцию, например, окно Ханна (в вашем случае 1-0.35*w(n))

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Пардон за долгий ответ, добавил ссылку на csv файл и в тексте вопроса пример данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не самый качественный способ, зато самый простой. Натренированный глаз может заметить переход - кривая стала непрерывной, но разрывы в производной видны.

```
# загрузка данных
df = pd.read_json(json_data).set_index('date')

# изготовление перехода длиной десять дней
df['factor'] = np.where(df.index >= '2023-07-17', 0.65, 1.0)
df['factor'] = df['factor'].rolling('10d').mean()
df['coef'] *= df['factor']

# рисование
df.plot(y='coef')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]